# Forcing HTML table rows to fill screen

Tags: html, css

I know questions similar to this have been asked many times, and I have tried answer after answer to no avail.  I am trying to format an HTML page, and I was attempting to use tables in order to position everything.

So I created a 3x3 grid using tables and filled it with the information I wanted to include.  The problem I am running into is that empty cells take up no space which means that rows or columns with empty cells aren't formatted properly.

Is there a way to force my rows to fill the entire height of the window?  I'd like to have all 9 'cells' be of equal size.
Thank you!

Below is one attempt at the formatting.  I've included borders around the cells to make them more visible and removed the image which is stored on my computer:

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Audiowide' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <style>
        html {height: 100%; width: 100%;}
        body {background-color: black; min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%;font-family: 'Audiowide', Lucida Console, Lucida, sans-serif;}
        table {table-layout: fixed; width: 100%; min-height: 100%; border: 1px solid white;}
        #outer {width: 100%; height: 100%;}
        #img {float: left}
        .container {width=33%; height=33%; border-radius: 3px; background-color: #afafaf;}
        #inner {}
        .text {color: black; font-size: 16px;}
        #sub {margin-left:45%; width: 10%; text-align: center; color: black}
        #nAcc {margin:auto; text-align: center; color: black}
        td, tr {border: 1px solid white;}
        .spacing {height=100% width=100%;};
        a {text-decoration: none;}

    </style>

    <title>Ethan's Messenger</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="spacing">
    <table id="outer">
        <tr>
            <td id="img"><img src="" id="logo" /></td>
            <td>&nbsp</td>
            <td>&nbsp</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp</td>
            <td>
                <div class="container">
                    <form><table id="inner">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="text">Username:</td>
                            <td><input type="text" style="width:100%"></element></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="text">Password:</td>
                            <td><input type="text" style="width:100%"></element></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" id="sub"></element></td></tr>
                        <tr><td colspan="2"><a href="/nAcc/"><p id="nAcc">Create A New Account</p></a></td></tr>
                    </table></form>
                </div>
            </td>
        <td>&nbsp</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp</td>
        <td>&nbsp</td>
        <td>&nbsp</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
body {
  background-color: black;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Audiowide', Lucida Console, Lucida, sans-serif;
}
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
#outer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#img {
  float: left
}
.container {
  width=33%;
  height=33%;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #afafaf;
}
#inner {} .text {
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
}
#sub {
  margin-left: 45%;
  width: 10%;
  text-align: center;
  color: black
}
#nAcc {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: black
}
td,
tr {
  border: 1px solid white;
}
.spacing {
  height=100% width=100%;
}
;
 a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Audiowide' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>



<div class="spacing">
  <table id="outer">
    <tr>
      <td id="img">
        <img src="" id="logo" />
      </td>
      <td>&nbsp</td>
      <td>&nbsp</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp</td>
      <td>
        <div class="container">
          <form>
            <table id="inner">
              <tr>
                <td class="text">Username:</td>
                <td>
                  <input type="text" style="width:100%">
                  </element>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="text">Password:</td>
                <td>
                  <input type="text" style="width:100%">
                  </element>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                  <input type="submit" id="sub">
                  </element>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                  <a href="/nAcc/">
                    <p id="nAcc">Create A New Account</p>
                  </a>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </form>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>&nbsp</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp</td>
      <td>&nbsp</td>
      <td>&nbsp</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the desired outcome you are looking for but if you change the `height` of the `table` to `100vh` instead of `100%` it will fill the entire view.

Comment: I had tried using 100vh in place of 100% before, and for some reason I was getting weird boxes.  I probably had messed with too many things at once.  Anyway, for anyone else who is attempting this, you may have to deal with overflow, I added "overflow: hidden" to my html style tag.

Answer (score 0):

This does not look like valid CSS....

```
.spacing {height=100% width=100%;};
```

Should be

```
 .spacing {height:100%; width:100%;}
```

Same with some of the inline style...

```
style="width:100%"
```

Should be

```
style="width:100%;"
```